# Is there an idiomatic way to define in AngularJS relationships between data models, similar to Ember Data?

Tags: angularjs, ember.js

I really like the promise of [Ember Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data), and am wondering if there is an idiomatic way to accomplish the same thing in AngularJS.  It seems like there isn't, that you have to manage your models manually as opposed to something like this, from http://emberjs.com/guides/models/ .

```
App.Order = DS.Model.extend({
  lineItems: DS.hasMany('lineItem')
});

App.LineItem = DS.Model.extend({
  order: DS.belongsTo('order')
});
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045964/angularjs-models), but it doesn't seem to get at exactly what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Consider checking out breeze.js as well - it a little more work than ember-data to set up but provides more functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is up to you but there are some tools to help with that:

You have your own REST API.

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular

Websocket based database.

https://www.firebase.com/quickstart/angularjs.html

Personally I use a simple generic $http wrapper service to make simple api calls.  Especially for when my requests aren't REST for whatever reason.

Other than this I haven't found I needed models when I let my API do most of the work.  I speak from building a massively scalable application for business.

Comment: And then can't you nest routes so that AngularJS can intelligently handle parent-child relationships?  Isn't that built into AngularJS?

Comment: @AliNabavi That's what I'd use Restangular for.  Angular's focus is just be a good framework that is easily extendable on a good architecture.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Interesting.  I will try that out.